# Why are my angle calculations not working properly?

Tags: unity, c#, trigonometry, angles

I am using this code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HARcieveAngleChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float ha;
    private float HAZ;
    public ConfigurableJoint CJ;
    public Vector3 newanchor;
    public Vector3 newaxis;

    public void OnValueChangedHA(float newValue)
    {
        ha = (HAGrab.HAUpdate);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("ha WHAT YO DOING = " + ha);
        HAZ =(float)0.8 * (Mathf.Tan(ha))  ;
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("HAZ WHAT YO DOING = " + HAZ);
        transform.position = new Vector3(0,0, HAZ);
        newanchor.y = (float)-8;
        newanchor.z = -HAZ;
        newaxis.y = (float)8;
        newaxis.z = HAZ;
        CJ.connectedAnchor = newanchor;
        CJ.secondaryAxis = newaxis;


    }

}
```

From the `debug.log(ha)`, I am getting 45 when I enter a 45 value into the input UI. The `HAGrab` code gets this. However, the value outputted for `HAZ` always comes out incorrect (i.e. using trig TOA, `tan(angle)*length` of alternate side = opposite side, with a 45 degree angle it should come out as 0.8)...

Does anyone have any ideas for why this is the case?

Comment: Did you mean to convert your degree value into radians with `Mathf.Deg2Rad`, since trig functions take their input in radians?

Comment: I had already tried that as i read online to take it in radians, but it still wasn't coming out right so I'm not sure what else it could be

Comment: Your first problem with be that your `ha` variable needs to be in radians. see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Tan.html). I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but you will not get the correct calculations using angles here. Convert the angles to radians first, and try to identify the next problem

Comment: I went back and tried it again putting the conversion in a different line rather than in the equation itself and is now working, thanks to both of you for the help

Answer (score 0):

To convert degrees to radians, you need to multiply the angle in degrees by Mathf.PI / 180.0f.

```
HAZ = (float)0.8 * Mathf.Tan((ha * Mathf.PI) / 180.0f);
```

Comment: Unity has a built-in constant for this: `Mathf.Deg2Rad`

Comment: Your math is correct! For reference in environments without the mentioned `Deg2Rad`, it's generally better practice to wrap the constants together like `tan(angle * (PI / 180))`. This reduces down to a single runtime multiplication instead of both a multiplication and a division.